# Anonymous Apex - System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 - No DML In LOOP?

Tags: apex, limitexception

I am getting the "Too Many SOQL queries" error on the code below when executing as anonymous APEX in my sandbox.  But by my reading of "best practices" I thought I'm doing things right - I was careful not to do DML inside any loop.  The list I'm trying to update is about 4000 records.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

```
List<Case> caseList = [
    SELECT ID
    ,CASENUMBER
    ,ISCLOSED
    ,CreatedDate
    ,CLOSEDDATE
    ,status
    ,Request_Received_Date_Time__c
    ,Case_Resolution_Date_Time__c
    ,Request_To_Resolution_Business_Hours__c
    FROM CASE 
    WHERE ISCLOSED = true
    and calendar_year(createddate) = 2018
    AND Request_To_Resolution_Business_Hours__c = NULL
];

System.debug('caseList Size: ' + caseList.size()); // that list is going to be about 4000 records for 2018

BusinessHours bh = [
    SELECT FridayEndTime        
        ,FridayStartTime
        ,Id
        ,IsActive
        ,IsDefault
        ,LastModifiedById
        ,LastModifiedDate
        ,MondayEndTime
        ,MondayStartTime
        ,Name
        ,SaturdayEndTime
        ,SaturdayStartTime
        ,SundayEndTime
        ,SundayStartTime
        ,SystemModstamp
        ,ThursdayEndTime
        ,ThursdayStartTime
        ,TimeZoneSidKey
        ,TuesdayEndTime
        ,TuesdayStartTime
        ,WednesdayEndTime
        ,WednesdayStartTime FROM BusinessHours where Name='xxxxx'
    LIMIT 1
];

For(Case case_record : caseList){
    try{        
        DateTime startDate, endDate;
        if(case_record.Request_Received_Date_Time__c!=null) { startDate = case_record.Request_Received_Date_Time__c; }
            else{ startDate = case_record.CreatedDate; }                    
        if(case_record.Case_Resolution_Date_Time__c!=null) { endDate = case_record.Case_Resolution_Date_Time__c; }
            else{ endDate = case_record.ClosedDate; }


        Double requestToResolution = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, startDate, endDate)/3600000.0;

        case_record.Request_To_Resolution_Business_Hours__c = requestToResolution;

        System.debug('Case ' + case_record.CASENUMBER + ' Request_To_Resolution_Business_Hours__c updated to: ' + requestToResolution);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('General Unhandled Exception on case ' + case_record.CASENUMBER + ' ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}

Update caseList;
```

Comment: There is a high chance that there is a trigger on Case or related object, which is not able to handle simultaneous update of 4k of records with less then 100 soql queries (basically less then 5 SOQL queries per chunk of 200 records) .

Comment: Thanks, all.  This was exactly it.  I found the trigger and did not want to disable/re-enable it so I took the route suggested in the answer - I batched my updates with a LIMIT in the SOQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kurunve has a point, if you have trigger on Case sObject and you're retrieving about 4k rows, then it definitely can exceed the limit of SOQL queries in one transaction.

**Workaround**:
Process your records in several transactions:

```
List<Case> caseList = [
    SELECT ...
    FROM CASE 
    WHERE ISCLOSED = true
    and calendar_year(createddate) = 2018
    AND Request_To_Resolution_Business_Hours__c = NULL
    LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
];
```

Take a constant limit (increase or decrease it in a way that suits you) and change offset for the next execution.

Comment: don't forget that max value for `OFFSET` is only 2000. Anything above 2000 will result in an QueryException. Based on his code I'd say that `Request_To_Resolution_Business_Hours__c = NULL` criteria is enough for his needs